# "Didn't choose {to be born/to have been born}"

Tags: tense, past-tense

> 1. Didn't choose **to be** born
> 2. Didn't choose **to have been** born

The second one doesn't sound right to me, but something about it looks plausible. Which one is the right one, and why?

Comment: **didn't choose** (simple past) governs the choice here and it wants the simple "to be born". But without **didn't choose**, all you'd need is the requisite temporal circumstance to justify the perfect. *To have been born on a planet with but one moon instead of three was his nightly disappointment.* or *If he were given the choice, he would choose to have been born on a planet with three moons.*

Comment: Could you elaborate on temporal circumstance? I can't find any mention of it in my textbooks.

Comment: "Temporal circumstance" is a very fancy way of saying "situation."  @Tᴚoɯɐuo was explaining that to use "to have been" you need a reason.  There was no reason given in your examples, so it should not be used.

Comment: But situation in respect to time.   To be in hot water is different from having been in hot water.

Answer (score 0):

"Didn't choose to be born" is the correct form.  "Didn't choose to have been born" is the phrasing that would be used if being born was a repeated or continuing action.

Comment: I'd say no, the condition of having been born is continuous; neither implies repetition.